# Your active platform is: JDK_1.6, but the corresponding property "platforms.JDK_1.6.home" is not found in the project's properties files

Tags: java, netbeans, platform, java-6

I'm a Java noob (but have been programming for 25+ years, and have worked with OO languages from day 1).

All of a sudden I started getting this error:

```
Your active platform is: JDK_1.6, but the corresponding property "platforms.JDK_1.6.home" is not found in the project's properties files.
```

Not sure what caused this condition, and not sure what Java's asking me to do. I'm working in the NetBeans IDE. The last thing I attempted to do is add some binary (image) resources to my project.

Comment: I think this is a NetBeans error, not a Java error.

Comment: Did you fin solution to this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It means you haven't told netbeans where your Java 1.6 installation is.   Go into settings, add the JDK (JDK->Add->New), and select the directory above 'bin' for your JDK16.

Comment: Nope! That didn't do it. And this is a project that I've been working with for a while, so I'm sure my JDK is set right....

Comment: Certainly looks like a netbeans error - your project files are just ascii text, I'd check there - see if the variable is not there or the file is corrupt (the property file). Maybe some weird unescaped quote or something?

Answer (score 5):

In my case the JDK setup in Netbeans was fine. It was just one of those strange Netbeans issues that come out of nowhere.

**My fix was:**

Clear the Netbeans Cache i.e. delete the folder:
C:\Users\\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache\

Comment: Big thanks, that resolved it for me. I had no errors in the properties file, it was just the cache giving trouble. Adding removing the platform as per some other suggestions had no effect.

Answer (score 2):

This error can occur at two scenarios:

1. Right click your netbean project -> Properties -> Libraries
   After select Libraries , right panel on top  you can see "Java Platform" combo box. This Jave Platform is missing for your project. You need to add using Manage Platforms bottom beside Jave Platform combo box.
2. Even thought scenario (1) is correct it can happen. Because your project has reference to another netbean project in your Libraries. This reference project is missing Jave Platform.

Answer (score 2):

I have Linux in my office and Mac in Home and this problem is frequently when I share projects in github, I solve it removing the build directory and doing clean and build.

Answer (score 0):

Right click on project - Properties - Libraries - Select the correct jdk version from the Java Platform combobox.

Answer (score 0):

NetBeans bug

1. If your project depends on other projects, open and clean build all of them(that fixed it for me).
2. Most likely cache-related stuff. Clean up NB cache as suggested by someone before

Answer (score 0):

You should remove the files under private folder in the nbproperties folders.

Answer (score 0):

for me any recommended way early didn't helped, but changing in project Properties -> Source/Binary format to JDK 7, Save than change back to JDK 8 fixed this error